# Detect when an user sends a sticker in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Is there a way to detect when an user sends a sticker in discord.js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```js
if(message.stickers.size == 1) return console.log("user sent a sticker!")
```

Also I recommend you checking [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=stickers)!

Comment: alright, i remember now, i didnt check the docs cause theyre always offline. when i do a console.log(message.stickers) i get undefined back, why is that? running on v12 here.

Comment: @lolc It's not possible to get message stickers in discord.js v12 because it was added in discord.js v13